# Custom toggle switch with simple html

Tags: html, css

I'm following some examples to create a custom toggle.

The HTML for this toggle looks very unfamiliar.

I am looking for an HTML expression like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="inline">
```

Instead, I have this:

```
    mixin model
  section&attributes(attributes)= name
    .checkbox
      input(type='checkbox')
      label
- var x  =1
  +model(class="model-1")
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBEyWz

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? You appear to already have a toggle that is built with only HTML + CSS. What problem are you having with the code you have at the moment? Are you asking how to understand the mixin?

Comment: @ObsidianAge zer00ne mentioned that it's Vue not html.

Comment: Here's the **simplest** checkbox switch - https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/YzRqgjO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That unfamiliar code is from Vue I think. Vue is a JavaScript framework like React or Angular -- so I assume that you are looking for a HTML/CSS solution for a toggle button. The following demo is an adaptation of an example found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp).

```css
:root {
  font: 700 16px/1 Verdana;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3.75em;
  height: 2.125em;
}

.control {
  display: none
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 2.125em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.625em;
  width: 1.625em;
  left: 0.25em;
  bottom: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: .4s;
}

.control:checked+.switch .slider {
  background: rgba(128, 255, 128, 1);
}

.control:checked+.switch .slider::before {
  transform: translateX(1.625em);
}
```

```html
<input id='control' class='control' type="checkbox">
<label class="switch" for='control'>
  <output class="slider" for='control'></output>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might get you started:

```
$('#inline').click(function(){
    $('#mydiv').toggleClass('bgred');
});
```

#### Demo:

```js
$('#inline').click(function(){
  $('#mydiv').toggleClass('bgred');
});
```

```css
#inline{transform:scale(1.8);}
#mydiv{margin-top:50px;height:100px;width:250px;background:blue;}
.bgred{background:red !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Check: <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="inline">

<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

---

Here is another example, with a label -- and using a variable to keep track of the button state (instead of relying on jQuery's `toggleClass` method):

#### Demo The Seconde:

```js
var outer_scope_var = false;
$('#inline').click(function(){
    if (outer_scope_var){
        $('#mydiv').removeClass('bgred');
        outer_scope_var = false;
    }else{
        $('#mydiv').addClass('bgred');
        outer_scope_var = true;
    }
});
```

```css
#inline{transform:scale(1.8);}
#mydiv{margin-top:50px;height:100px;width:250px;background:blue;}
.bgred{background:red !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="inline">Click Words or Box:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="inline">

<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Would that work for a toggle? A toggle has an extra "label" element and the css connects differently like in my example

Comment: I think the css in your question is SASS or LESS or some such. These are *preprocessed* CSS helpers - they allow you to do cool things while writing CSS, but they ***compile*** into ordinary CSS. In other words: (1) you can use ordinary CSS with them, no problem; and (2) *that* CSS needs to be compiled/preprocessed before it can be used. My example uses just ordinary CSS and jQuery/javascript. *jQuery makes it much easier/shorter to write javascript and is by far the most popular javascript library, [used on approx 75% of websites.](https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/js-jquery/all/all)*

Comment: I added another example showing use of a `<label>` tag (allows you to toggle checkbox either by clicking on box or on associated words), and also replaced the jQuery toggleClass method with a manual toggle system *(to show you how the toggleClass method works under the hood -- it is very simple, as you can see.)* Note that the manual system is more reliable and flexible.